# Is there a tool for verifying the contents of a Zip archive against the source directory's contents?

Tags: compression, zip, cross-platform

Here's the scenario:

- I create a ZIP archive using some GUI package like WinZip, 7-Zip or whatever by right-clicking on a directory "somename" and selecting "Compress to archive 'somename.zip'"
- When the archive is completed, I open it and discover that some files don't exist in the archive (for reasons yet unknown).
- I want to find all files that are missing from the archive without having to extract the archive to another directory, then doing directory diff, etc.

So..

Is there a tool (GUI or command-line, standalone or built into a compressor, for Windows or Linux, I don't care) that can walk through an archive and compare its contents against a directory on the filesystem?

Comment: Do you have files that are hidden, system, read-only, encrypted and/or with/without the archive flag that your zip software is configured to ignore?

Comment: @DMA57361 - No, the files have standard attributes and are not encrypted. I have a sneaking suspicion that non-English (Unicode) characters in the filenames have something to do with it. It's possibly a bug in the compressor..I want to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse:  Why did you remove jZip??

Comment: @Paradroid: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1860/jzip-possible-malicious-software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a free tool, but [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) supports this.  If you're going to be doing much as far as diffs go Beyond Compare is well worth the cost.