# How to compare files inside and outside of a zip file in Windows?

Tags: compression, file-comparison

When I archive a large number of files in a zip file using 7-Zip in Windows, I'd like to verify that the compression was performed without error. In order to do this, I need to compare the original files with the files stored in the zip file. Is there a way to do that?

Obviously, this can be done by unpacking the zip file and comparing the output to the original. I'm looking for a way to do the comparison without that overhead.

There was a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/201999/is-there-a-tool-for-verifying-the-contents-of-a-zip-archive-against-the-source-d), but it was only about verifying the list of files that got zipped, not verifying the files themselves, which is what I need.

The answer to that question suggested using *BeyondCompare*. The [feature list](http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=features_list) seems to indicate this program can do what I need, at the cost of $30. I could buy that if necessary, but I wonder if people have other suggestions. And if there's not another way to do it, then I wonder if *BeyondCompare* is just unpacking the zip itself for comparison, so that I wouldn't be doing any better by using that than by running a PowerShell script like that suggested in the comment by "HelpingHand".

Comment: I would probably use PowerShell to unpack the zip back out and then compare all the checksums from the original source and the structure should be the same,  See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-compare-two-files/

Comment: Maybe something like https://pastebin.com/xMMiWmS3 as a start?

Comment: As I've explained in my edit of the question, I'm looking for a way to do this without unpacking the zip file. But if I have to do that, your script will give me a head start at it, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be to walk the entire way even if it's resource hungry.

Add file.exe to file.zip
extract file.zip to zip/file.exe
compare file.exe zip/file.exe
for example using diff

Another bonus is that I assume there is a reason for you to worry about corruption of the files, and you should be able to spot, for instance memory/disk corruption this way. (exact same procedure give diffrent result)

Comment: I've just edited the question to explain that I'm looking for a way to do this without unpacking the zip file.